# Finding strongly connected components in a directed graph using Kosaraju's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph

I'm working through Stanford's algorithms course on edX.

One of the programming assignments is to find strongly connected components using Kosaraju's algorithm, on a graph with ~875,000 vertices. My implementation is the most basic translation from the textbook's pseudo code into Python, and it works fine on smaller graphs, so I think it's correct.

With Python's default recursion limit of 1000 it reaches the limit.

I've tried `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)`, but that doesn't help, and instead I get "Process finished with exit code -1073741571" which is a stack overflow.

````
G = {}
for i in range(1, 875715):
    G[i] = [0] #Each dictionary entry is a list. The first element of the list is 0 if the vertex is unexplored, otherwise 1.
for l in open('SCC.txt'):
    items = list(map(int, l.split()))
    G[items[0]].append(items[1])

Grev = {} #The same graph, with the edges reversed.
for i in range(1, 875715):
    Grev[i] = [0]
for l in open('SCC.txt'):
    items = list(map(int, l.split()))
    Grev[items[1]].append(items[0])

def TopoSort(G): #Topological sort on the reversed graph.
    for v in G:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            DFStopo(G, v)

def DFStopo(G, s): 
    G[s][0] = 1
    global orderedVertexList #The order in which to run DFS and assign SCCs.
    for v in G[s][1:]:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            DFStopo(G, v)
    orderedVertexList.insert(0, s)

def Kosaraju(G, Grev):
    TopoSort(Grev)
    global numSCC
    for v in orderedVertexList:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            numSCC = numSCC + 1
            DFSSCC(G, v)

def DFSSCC(G, s):
    G[s][0] = 1
    global SCC
    SCC.append(numSCC) #The submission only requires the size of the five largest SCCs, so order doesn't matter.
    for v in G[s][1:]:
        if G[v][0] == 0:
            DFSSCC(G, v)

numSCC = 0
orderedVertexList = []
SCC = []

Kosaraju(copy.deepcopy(G), copy.deepcopy(Grev))
```
````

Comment: [Initially asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63732271#comment112699640_63732271)